# Algorithm: Unable to understand this Programming Challenge

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I am unable to understand this question.What this question want us to find and what is given.Can anyone just explain it in a naive manner .

***Question***

> The Sheriff of the Hackers' community had a very urgent job to do. He
>   needs to diffuse all the bombs placed by Joker. Joker is extremely
>   clever and cruel. He selected a region of 1000 X 1000 points, chose N
>   center points of the form (X,Y) and placed bombs on every integral
>   point that was on or inside the circular region of radius R around
>   that chosen point. Then he went to every such point and activated
>   those bombs that lied on or inside at least two such circular regions.
>
> In order to make an efficient plan for the Bomb Disposal Squad, You
>   need to help the Sheriff to determine the number of active bombs.

**INPUT:**

> The first line of the input contains the N. Next N lines contain 3
>   space separated integers X Y R as described above.

***OUTPUT:***

> Print the number of active bombs.

CONSTRAINTS:
1 <= N <= 10
1 <= X,Y,R <= 1000
**NOTE :**

> The search area for the Sheriff is a square with diagonal points (1,1)
>   and (1000,1000)

**Sample Input**

```
2 
5 5 2 
3 4 3
```

**Sample Output**

> 9

**Explanation**

> All of the following 9 points are inside atleast 2 circles

```
3 5
4 4
4 5
4 6
5 3
5 4
5 5
5 6
6 4
```

I have no idea how to approach this problem.Where did the joker plant the bomb and how should I check for it whether a particular region has bomb planted.Sorry I might have misunderstood this also.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet>?

Comment: try reading up on distance computing formulae like pythogoras's theorem

Comment: @mohit I said I am clueless. How could I approach if i don't understand what is given in the question.

Comment: @Jasen I will study if I know that part is required in solving this problem.I am not getting what the question is ;solution comes later

Comment: Stack overflow isn't the right place to ask this, since it's not about programming.. it's about English comprehension. For what it's worth, the question is asking how many points (with x and y both integers and between 1 and 1000) are there in the circles described by the input.

Comment: @Anonymous If I am unable to understand a  Programming problem where else should I post.I am using this site for long time for clarifying my doubts and that's what I have done here.btw Its not about comprehension but the puzzle which I was unable to understand.

Comment: So you comprehend the problem description, but don't understand the programming problem? (One approach in problems with a geometrical interpretation is [reducing it's dimensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm): finding the number of points of a two dimensional grid inside more than one of at most ten circles is not trivial - how about the points on one, say, vertical line of the grid? Where does outside/inside change? And how does it change going to the next line? The number of circles is no worry here, as it is strictly limited - start with two, then three.)

Answer (score 1):

the best way to explain this is starting with squares....

imagine a grid as such:

```
a 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
b 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
c 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
d 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
e 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
f 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Lets say the center point was (c,4) and the width was 3.  Your square would be drawn on points (b,3) (b,4) (b,5)(c,3),(d,3) (d,4) (d,5) (c,5)

(c,4) would be in the middle.....

So... with a square you would have 9 (add up all the edge points I described and the center point which is contained in the square).

You are being asked to do the same thing..... with circles....  Good luck...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to explain what this question wants is:

Given a list of circles, defined by a center (X, Y) and a radius (R), how many integral points (i.e. integers, (1,4) vs (1.1, 4.4)) of the 1000x1000 grid are within 2 or more of those circles.

That's what is being asked.

There are a lot of ways this could be solved, but that would be a different questions.

The most basic technique would be to iterate across all 1000x1000 points, calculate teh distance from each point to the center of each circle, and for those points who distance is less than R for a given circle, add 1. All points with a value more than 1 would be reported.

This is not necessarily the most efficient algorithm. For example, if there are 4 circles in the list, you would be calculating 4,000,000 distances.

But it will work.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to solve this. One way is to check each point in the matrix to see how many circles it lies in. Another way is to keep a list of points inside a circle, and increment a counter if the point already exists.

Comment: thanks .Could you explain what this question want me to find?